# Sending dates into postgresql

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have some doubts about this one, I have gone through others topics but I still can't get the code workig properly.

My intent is to insert dates into my DB using JDBC, I'm using a jTextField (or a JformattedField, trying both ways) and all I get is an error from the database. Its Because I'm sending text instead date, so, how can I send dates ?

EDIT1: I'm trying to send date of birth.

Already made some tries, that's why I have:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
    java.sql.Date data = new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse().getTime());
```

code:

```
try {   
        conecta.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        PreparedStatement pst = conecta.conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cad_pessoa(cad_cpf,cad_nome, cad_idade, cad_apelido, cad_data) values (?,?,?,?,?)");

        
        pst.setString(1, jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText()); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
        pst.setString(2, jTextFieldNOME.getText()); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
        pst.setString(3, jTextFieldIDADE.getText()); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
        pst.setString(4, jTextFieldApelido.getText());//pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
        SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy");
        java.sql.Date data = new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse().getTime());
        pst.setDate(5, formatter.parse(jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText())); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
        pst.executeUpdate(); //executa o SQL
        
        
        conecta.conn.commit();
        
        
        jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setText(""); //deixa o campo vazio
        jTextFieldNOME.setText(""); //deixa o campo vazio
        jTextFieldIDADE.setText(""); //deixa o campo vazio
        jFormattedTextFieldDATA.setText("");
        jTextFieldApelido.setText(""); //deixa o campo vazio
        
        jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldNOME.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldIDADE.setEnabled(false);
        jFormattedTextFieldDATA.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldApelido.setEnabled(false);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Salvo!");
        
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Erro!\n" +ex);

    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set a date using `setInt`? You may want to consider not using `java.sql.Date`, and instead use `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: Already fixed the setInt for setDate, and im trying to send date of birth.

Comment: That's great, but using `java.time.LocalDate` (with `setObject`) is the better choice when using recent JDBC drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setInt()` method that you use is intended for integer values, and it accepts an integer. To set the date, use the `PreparedStatement.setDate()` method.

The `java.util.Date` you get from the `parse()` method should also be converted to `java.sql.Date`.

```java
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date utilDate = formatter.parse(jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText());
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
pst.setDate(5, sqlDate);
```

See the documentation on the `PreparedStatement` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Comment: I tried use setDate but still no solution.

error: incompatible types: java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date
            pst.setDate(5, formatter.parse(jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText())); //pega o texto insirido e armazena no banco de dados
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output

Comment: Yes, the `java.util.Date` should be converted to `java.sql.Date` first. I've updated the code in the answer.

Comment: Seems we are in the right path, but still get an error 

error: cannot find symbol
            java.util.Date utilDate = formatter.parse(jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText());
  symbol:   variable formatter
  location: class Pessoa

Comment: The `formatter` variable is declared in your code, so I can't say what's wrong without looking at the current state of your code. I've added the `formatter` initialization to my code sample just in case.

Comment: I deleted the formatter and didn't notice, I have put back on the code and now it's working properly, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Never use `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and such. These legacy date-time classes are *terrible*, tragically flawed in design.

The legacy classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## `java.time.LocalDate`

Parse your input string as a [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ; 
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( input , f ) ;
```

Pass to your database via your prepared statement.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

To retrieve from the database:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

In Postgres, you would define your column to be of type [`DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with version 4.2 or later of the [JDBC specification](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221).

All of this has been covered many many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

pst.setInt(5, formatter.parse(jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText()));

This is the culprit line. See you are using setInt() method in order to set a date. That is absolutely incorrect. Use setDate() method instead.

eg: pst.setDate(5, formatter.parse(jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText()));